# Extracting LZO1 Files - C#

Tags: c#, file, extract

I was wondering how I could extract files using C#. I know a lot of you will say that tons of people have asked questions on extracting files using C#, but I believe the compression format I am trying to decompress is LZO. I'm not exactly sure how it works, and I have looked all over for some classes that will do it. Also, this file doesn't have the LZO magic at the top of the file, but I'm still pretty sure that it is LZO. I think this because I have downloaded another tool that was built in C++, and requires the "lzo1.dll"[(download)](http://www.fileserve.com/file/78cQXdN/lzo1.dll). I will also contain the file below that I am trying to figure out how to extract. Thanks for any help :)

Trying to Extract: http://www.fileserve.com/file/bzV4XEz/Save0.sgd

Also, this is the information that the program that can extract showed me after extracting it: http://pastebin.com/xmHtZagG

Comment: A quick search on Google turned up LZO.Net: http://lzo-net.sourceforge.net/, and QuickLZ: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ManagedQLZ.aspx, and several others.

Comment: Well, as far as the LZO.Net dll, I actually did take a look at that and it didn't seem to work. Not sure if I'm stupid or something, but on the first line of code, it set a LZOCompressor equal to a LZOCompress, and it seems like LZOCompress doesn't exist in the DLL. Also, if you set a LZOCompressor equal to a LZOCompressor, then it throws an exception.

With the other one on CodeProject, it hasn't seemed to work. Do you know which bytes I should put in the QuickLZ.Decompress method, becuase if I put the whole file in there, it won't work...

Just wondering, have you tried any of those methods?

Comment: No, I haven't tried any of those. If I had something that worked I would have posted an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Was just wondering, wasn't trying to be a jerk. Don't take it personally...

Comment: Not a problem. I wasn't upset or anything, nor did I think you were being a jerk.

Comment: I've had best luck working just from lzo.dll. You'll need to write your own p/invoke signature, but most 'libraries' that adapt LZO to .NET go out of date or don't work on new .NET versions. You may also need to make sure you're calling the correct DLL for your system, 32 or 64 bit

Comment: I've also noticed that some libraries assume the last 4 bytes hold the uncompressed length. This isn't always the case. I've seen saved game files that store it in the first 4 bytes, instead. LZO.NET assumes this, and therefore fails. Use their code as a reference to write something that works for your case.

Answer (score 2):

That lzo1.dll file is a publically available version of an LZO decompression library. Since that appears to work on your file, you can try just using that, especially if the .NET LZO libraries aren't working for you.

It seems to have disappeared from the usual place (GnuWin32) but I found it here:

http://www.pytables.org/download/lzo-win/

Once you have that you can use P/Invoke to call the unmanaged methods in the library. The archive above includes the binaries, header files, and man pages -- everything you need to make your own C# P/Invoke translation. Just doing a decompression doesn't look too complex, only two calls:

```
[DllImport("lzo1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int lzo_init ( );

[DllImport("lzo1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int lzo1x_decompress ( 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=1)] byte[] src,
  int src_len,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=3)] byte[] dst,
  int dst_len,
  IntPtr wrkmem);
```

There appears to be a bunch of different _decompress methods, and you may just need to try them all to see which one works with your particular file. They all have the same signature, just different names. Look through the header files to see which ones there are.